# Personal Domain Email Integration

Tags: email, integration

i have a domain www.personal.pk with which i got my email... the company from which i got hosting from says the my email has following feature

- Email (pop3)
- IMAP Compatible
- WebMail
- Email Aliases (unlimited)
- Email Forwarding
- Catch All Email Address
- Auto Reply

the thing is i am accessing my email and all the others email through Webmail using a service provided by the company called "HORDE"... when i open an mail account i can see the inbox of other by just changing slection of a **select(dropdown) box\list**.. meaning on user can see the email of others.. somebody told me the solution is integrate it with google and use the Gmails interface... HOW TO DO IT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always thought that it could only be done with a domain purchased through Google. Anyway, you do it with a service called google apps:
http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/index.html

Comment: I didn't want to steal Adams answer since he's spot on the money, just wanted to put in a link directly to the free version since it may be hard to find from his link:

http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/group/index.html

Comment: Thanks for adding that... probably should've put that originally.

Comment: You can do it with any domain that you own and can change the DNS records on (`CNAME` and `MX`).

Comment: @Lèsemajesté Does the domain not need to have a mail server (i.e. )? I'm considering buying a domain on its own and pointing its DNS records to my Outlook account, but I'm not sure whether this would work.